# Jmeter -Illegal character found in host: '/'

Tags: jmeter

Thread Name:Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start:1970-01-01 05:30:00 IST
Load time:0
Connect Time:0
Latency:0
Size in bytes:839
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:839
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.MalformedURLException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Illegal character found in host: '/'

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null

Comment: what you put in Server Name field, show your request

Answer (score 7):

You cannot have `/` character neither in [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) nor in the [DNS hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname)

You need to split:

1. Protocol: http, https or file
2. Server name or ip
3. Path

into different fields like:

[image]

or in exceptional case you can put the whole URL into the "Path" field of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler:

[image]

---

In general it should be much faster and easier to get the "skeleton" of the test project  by just recording the test using [JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/), it will generate "proper" HTTP Request samplers from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the ${URL} variable, instead of putting that in the server name and ip section of the HTTP request, put that variable in the path section. That is only if the URL has the entire address of the site including the protocol.
E.g., ${URL}=https://thesitename.com.